# Find the first occurence of a character in a string (java)

Tags: java

The title. If it doesn't have the character in the string it's supposed to return -1. Here is what I have so far, but its not giving the desired output. It's giving me the ascii value of the character for some reason.

```
public static int findInStr(String s1, char c){
    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        if (s1.charAt(i) == c) 
            return s1.charAt(i);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Because your function return type is `int`. It will convert `char` to `int` and return the ASCII value.

Comment: Can you use s1.indexOf(c)?

Comment: If you're looking for the first index at which `c` is found, just `return i`.

Comment: use s1.indexOf(c)

Comment: What is "_the desired output_" ?

Comment: Say if the string was dazzling and character z   IN: dazzling z     OUT: 2

Comment: just `return i`

Comment: Thanks for the help I got it working.

Answer (score 3):

Just return i for index of character in string as :

```
public static int findInStr(String s1, char c){
for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
    if (s1.charAt(i) == c) 
        return i;
}
return -1;
```

}

You can also use this method without using for loop::

```
public static int findInStr(String s1, char c){
    return s1.indexOf(c);
```

}

If character is not present in string indexOf return -1 otherwise index of first occurrence of character